# Using Context to dim the screen

Tags: android, android-context

I'm wondering what "context" stands for in this code, and what shall I insert to make it work? (Code to dim the screen)

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                         Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);
```

Comment: context , means the Context of your current Activity , you can get it by this.getContext();

Comment: okej, how should the code be? 
this.getContext().getContentResolver()?

Comment: i've never try it , but i think it should me something like this : Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);

or : Settings.System.putInt(thisgetApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this from `Activity` or `Service`:

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);
```

That's because both `Activity` and `Service` are inherited from `Context` class and can be used as context value. You can make this even more explicit (still assuming this is class inherited from `Activity` or `Service`):

```
Context context = this;
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, someIntValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, there is no longer an error in the code, though the screen does not still change brightness eventhough I changed the "someIntValue" to a low, high number. Anyone who knows the answer to this question?

Comment: if you want to change the brightness , follow this link , it's useful : http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html